Can't connect Postgres db from vercel to Prisma in Next.js project
I am trying to connect Postgres db created on vercel to Prisma in Next.js project.
I copied this variables to .env file:
enter image description here
In schema.prisma I have code from here
enter image description here

some models

model Post {
  id        Int      @id @default(autoincrement())
  createdAt DateTime @default(now())
  updatedAt DateTime @updatedAt
  title     String   @db.VarChar(255)
  content   String?
  published Boolean  @default(false)
  author    User     @relation(fields: [authorId], references: [id])
  authorId  Int
}
...

I am trying to run this command:
npx prisma migrate dev --name init
And recieve an error:
Error: P1001: Can't reach database server at ...
Please make sure your database server is running at ....
What I am doing wrong?
